# Javascript Array value not changing after join

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript with Node.js, I'm not able to join the global array.

`test.csv` ends up containing `c,d`

```
var placeName = ["a","b"];
var csvFile = 'test.csv';
fs.readFile(csvFile, 'UTF-8', function(err, csv) {
  $.csv.toArrays(csv, {}, function(err, data) {
    for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
      console.log(data[i]); //Will print every csv line as a newline
      placeName.push(data[i][0].toString());
    }
  });
   console.log(placeName); //Inside the function the array show a,b,c,d
});

// Prints only a and b. Did not add c & d from the csv.
console.log(placeName);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of asynchronous behaviour of JavaScript. `console.log(placeName)` outside is executed before you even read your CSV file.

Comment: Gosh. How many questions like that will we keep seeing? :)

Comment: Can anyone update this code with async await? I'm unable to get it working